# What oop pattern is this and how it is used?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I've seen this code in multiple projects(usually laravel) that i support now and i can not determine which pattern is this. It looks somewhat alike Factory Method, but it is obviously not and has a stable implementation that pops up here and there.
Personally i like it(nice instatiating method) but i want to know more about it(name, purposes and other information).
Can you help me?

So basically it is like this

```php
class Foo implements Fooable
{
    public readonly $bar;
    
    
    private function make($bar)
    {
        $instance = new self();
        $instance->bar = $bar;
        
        return $instance;
    }
    
    public function process($bar) //or execute, that is a cqrs app but i saw that in non-cqrs too
    {
     $instance = $this->make($bar);
     //continue code
    }
}
```

Sometimes there is an protected/private constructor and make is static method that sets up the instance.  But there is always a make() method that returns set up self/static instance of class.

Comment: Don't you mean: `$instance = $this->make($bar);` or `$instance = self::make($bar);`? I guess this code can make sense in certain contexts, but there's no context here. I think this can be rewritten with a normal constructor and do the same thing. It would be different if the functions were **static**.

Comment: Yes, i've ment `$instance = $this->make($bar);`, sorry, for mistype.